# How to click radio button in table for handle multiple records?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am creating a table of class attendance module in which teacher clicks on a radio button in front of student name to mark that if he/she is present,absent or on leave and when we submit the rows are saved in MySQL database.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

**Problem:**
when teacher clicks on radio button the first student attendance got marked and when teacher click on the second student's attendance it also get marked but the marked attendance of the first student get unmarked. **The error is teacher can only mark one student attendance at a time but I want to add multiple students attendance in MySQL table** .....

And this is my code
**code:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="class_id" value="<?php echo $row1['fk_class_id'];  ?>"  />
<input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php  echo  $row1['student_id']; ?>" />
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row1['first_name'];?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row1['last_name']; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row1['gender']; ?>"
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="att" value="P" />P
    <input type="radio" name="att" value="A" />A
    <input type="radio" name="att" value="L" />L
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: radio button mut have different name for each student

Comment: yes radio button has to have different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put an array as the name with the student_id:

```
<input type="radio" name="att[<?php echo $row1['student_id']; ?>]" value="P" />P
<input type="radio" name="att[<?php echo $row1['student_id']; ?>]" value="A"  />A
<input type="radio" name="att[<?php echo $row1['student_id']; ?>]" value="L" />L
```

the variable `$_POST['att']` will be an array with student_ids as keys.

```
  'att' => 
    array
      'student_1' => string 'P' 
      'student_2' => string 'A'
      'student_3' => string 'L'
```

Comment: now I am having problem in the post method an ideas for that?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: now when i try to post the data in my database this is the outcome " Array to string conversion in".

Comment: how do you get the result of the radio buttons ? be careful now `$_POST['att']` is an array.

Answer (score 3):

Each row is required to be treated as independent value, thus you must have the form act in such a way.

```
<!-- row 1 -->
<input type="radio" name="row1" value="P" />P
<input type="radio" name="row1" value="A"  />A
<input type="radio" name="row1" value="L" />L


<!-- row 2 -->
<input type="radio" name="row2" value="P" />P
<input type="radio" name="row2" value="A"  />A
<input type="radio" name="row2" value="L" />L
```

The way that radio buttons behave with one another is through the `name` attribute.

Rename each group of `att` buttons based on per row.